# importing and data handing in cycles

Tags: import, pattern-matching, sorting

I have a folder with many .dat files to analize, say

name_1.dat

name_2.dat

name_3.dat

.
.
.

name_n.dat

I also have an auxiliary property.dat file, which is a joint table with all the names:

name_1  property_1   property_2   property_3 ... property_m

name_2  property_1   property_2   property_3 ... property_m

name_3  property_1   property_2   property_3 ... property_m

.
.
.

name_n  property_1   property_2   property_3 ... property_m

with specific properties of those previous .dat files I mentioned but their names are not ordered as in the folder, they are like

name_10  property_1   property_2   property_3 ... property_m

name_8  property_1   property_2   property_3 ... property_m

name_1  property_1   property_2   property_3 ... property_m

.
.
.

name_n  property_1   property_2   property_3 ... property_m

.
.
.

name_5  property_1   property_2   property_3 ... property_m

I need to do cycle to process the data in the files but at the same time I need the properties of the other file to perform the analysis. During the cycle I need also to save individually the newly processed files and to write another file with the results, like

name_1  new_property_1

name_2  new_property_2

name_3  new_property_3

.
.
.

name_n  new_property_n

Could someone give me a hint on how to do that?

Comment: Look up `Module`, `Import`, `Do`, and `Export`.

Answer (score 1):

You have data files

```
dfile = FileNames["name_*.dat"];
```

One approach uses a loop. We derive property & output file names from the input (dat) filename using `StringReplace[]` & process as we go.

```
Do[
 (* set names *)
 pfile = StringReplace[dfile[[jf]], {".dat"->" property_1 property_2 property_3 ... property_m"}];
 ofile = StringReplace[dfile[[jf]], {".dat"->" new_property_1"}];
 (* get data *)
 ddata = Import[dfile[[jf]]];
 pdata = Import[pfile];

 (* process ... *)

 (* dump *)
 Export[ofile, results],
 {, jf, 1, Length@dfile}
];
```

Should get you started.

Preparation is key; having data as `StringJoin["Name_", IntegerString[#, 10, 2], ".dat"]& /@ Range[Length@data];` can save a lot of time.

There is an obvious functional approach.